# How to get input from a c program to a batch file as return value

Tags: c, batch-file

How to get input from a c program to a batch file as return value to access  menu by selecting a number among 1 - 4 . The numbers are given as user input in c file.

For example:

```
:START

start cChoice.exe

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO ONE 
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO TWO 
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO THREE 
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO FOUR

:ONE ECHO ONE Start notepad %1 exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:TWO ........
```

Help Plz. I am new in Batch..

Comment: You should reverse the order of your IF, because `IF ERRORLEVEL 1` matches everything equal or superior to 1. Begin with 4, then 3, 2, 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value from `main()` is the value of ERRORLEVEL. Alternatively the value passed to the `exit()` function.

However the `start` command causes the process to run concurrently to the batch file in a different cmd instance, so the batch file will not receive the errorlevel.  You should have:

```
:START
cChoice.exe

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO ONE
```